# I can't decrypt send message AES

Tags: java, android, string, encryption, udp

I have problem with decrypting message from UDP receive.

My code:

```
byte[] receiveData= new byte[1024];

DatagramPacket pakiet = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
udp.receive(pakiet);

String wiadomosc = new String(pakiet.getData());
publishProgress(wiadomosc);
String szyfr = main.preferences.getString("SZYFR_TCP", "");
if(!szyfr.equals("1"))
{
    enc = new Encryptor(kluczByte, getCode());
    Log.e("myApp", "jestem 2");
    Log.e("message = ","" + wiadomosc);

    wiadomosc = enc.decrypt(wiadomosc);
    publishProgress(wiadomosc);
}
```

In the log I saw that variable `wiadomosc` has data and many bad characters like this:

[image]

The byte array `reciveData` has 1024 elements. I think that my receive message is shorter, so it have to add elements to 1024. How to remove these characters from the string? Because I can't decrypt this string because I get a "corrupted pad block" exception.

Comment: Note that you should definitely set  character encoding for the String constructor (and getBytes() on the other end.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you just get the buffer returned when you call `pakiet.getData()`. So you could just call `pakiet.getLength()` to get to the exact amount of data within the buffer. If you call the decrypt function with the correct offset and length you should have more success.

Answer (score 1):

UDP header contains the length of the UDP data. So there must be some API in java to extract that length. The length is in bytes. So initialize you `receivedData` wih that length.

Comment: I guess you receive the complete package at the same time, and then you use the methods in my answer to extract the length.

Comment: @owlstead : yeah might be you are right. I was just trying to point out that UDP header includes the length in bytes.

Comment: we can say anything we want anyway, the chances of being voted up by this arse is zero anyway. I guess we'll have to do it ourselves :)

Comment: @owlstead : yeah we will do the up voting part. He does not vote up. But I am sure he takes a look at the comments :P